# how does puppet server selects the manifests to run on an agent

Tags: puppet

From the documentation of puppet server I understand that you can configure a manifest directory on the server to store the puppet scripts.

Then each agent contacts the server to update its configuration. How do the scripts to be run are selected on the server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppet *manifests* (the usual term, rather than *scripts*) are normally organised into a *module* per OS component or service (e.g. `apache`, `ntp`, `postgresql`), with one or more *classes* that contain everything needed to configure it.

The Puppet class contains all of the files, package and service *resource* definitions for the OS component. At its simplest, it's something like:

```
class apache {
  package { "httpd":
    ensure => installed,
  } ->
  service { "httpd":
    ensure => running,
  }
}
```

The agent contacts the master for its *catalog* (list of resources to configure) and in this process, the host is *classified* and a list of classes will be *included* in the catalog.

At its simplest, you can have a *main manifest* ([doc](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/dirs_manifest.html)) containing lists of nodes with their hostnames and include the classes you want to use on them:

```
node foo.example.com {
  include apache
}
```

The main manifest is compiled automatically when an agent requests its catalog and if a node definition matches the name of an agent, its contents are also evaluated to include those classes. Maintaining lots of node definitions in code isn't very efficient.

You can also use Hiera and [hiera_include](https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/3.2/puppet.html#assigning-classes-to-nodes-with-hiera-hierainclude) to store the list of classes in external Hiera data files, then a main manifest contains `hiera_include('classes')`. This looks up the value of `classes` from Hiera and then includes all of those classes.

Lastly, the master can be configured with an [External Node Classifier](https://docs.puppet.com/guides/external_nodes.html) (ENC), which is usually a script that's called when the agent checks in. It's given the name of the agent and should output a list of classes (and optionally, parameters and the *environment*). It could use a database or any sort of information you have in your organisation.